# Rails will_paginate minor bug when moving to next page

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have a small bug when going to the next page of a paginated list. My problem is that when I click on the next page after scrolling all the way down, my page doesn't load from the top, but instead bounces back down to the pagination links. It is easier to see what I mean by just going to my website [LazyHub](http://www.lazyhub.com) and testing it out. When I move to another page of articles, I would like for it to start from the top. Here is my relevant code parts:

html:

```
<div id = "pagination" class = "digg_pagination"><%= will_paginate @articles %></div>
```

css:

```
#pagination
{
clear: both;
margin-left: 215px;
}
```

controller:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @page = "home"
    @articles = Article.all.sort_by! { |a| [a.isOld ? 1 : 0, -a.get_upvotes.size, -a.views, -a.created_at.to_i, -a.id]}.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
  end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: After some further research, it seems like the behavior is correct in firefox, but not chrome. Hopefully that helps with understanding the problem.

Comment: is it an ajax request ?, if so you need to scroll to the top of the page after getting the response back.

Comment: @fanta it's using the will_paginate gem, and I'm not doing anything ajax related. It's weird cause it works in firefox but not chrome or safari.

Comment: How many Articles do you have in the database? I tried to check your page and took very long to load and then it crashed :( It's maybe because there is many of them and using `Article.all`  (that loads all Articles) is pretty bad idea. I would recommend getting rid of it and using ActiveRecord `order` instead of `sort_by`.